# Spring Data JPA - Save causes error with instead of insert trigger in output statement

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using the SQL Server database. We have "instead of insert" trigger where we insert the record and it returns `id`, `created`, and `deleted` columns' value. I have the code snippet given below:

```
insert into [Employee] (
        [Code], 
        [Name],
        [Created], [Deleted]
        ) 
        output [inserted].[Id],[inserted].[Created],[inserted].[Deleted]
    select [Code], 
        [Name],
        SYSUTCDATETIME(), [Deleted]
    from [inserted];
```

We are using `CrudRepository<Employee, Long>` to perform CRUD operation in Spring Boot Application. But when we call the save method of Repository, it causes following issue:

```
    2020-07-23 10:38:24.581  WARN 1960 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2020-07-23 10:38:24.582 ERROR 1960 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : A result set was generated for update.

Message: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
Cause: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
stack trace: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@874d53d
```

If we remove the output statement from `instead of insert` trigger, then save works fine. But I am not able to get `Id` column' value.

```
***
output [inserted].[Id],[inserted].[Created],[inserted].[Deleted]
***
```

Why does the output statement not returning the value and causes the error and how to get Id Column value?

Kindly share your thoughts on how we can handle this?

## Here is my entity class:

```
 import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "Code", nullable = false)
    private String code;
    
    @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "Created")
    private Date created;
    
    @Column(name = "Deleted")
    private Date deleted;

    public GlCountry() {

    }
    
    public GlCountry(String code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public GlCountry(int id, String code, String name, Date created, Date deleted) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.created = created;
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

  --- getter and Setter ---

}
```

## Trigger:

```
 ALTER trigger [dbo].[trg_Employee_InsteadOfInsertUpdateDelete] on [dbo].[Employee]
    instead of insert, update, delete
as
begin
    declare @inserted bit = 0
    declare @deleted bit = 0

    if exists(select top 1 1 from inserted) set @inserted = 1
    if exists(select top 1 1 from deleted) set @deleted = 1

    -- Decide on the operation that fired the trigger
    --
    if (@inserted = 1 and @deleted = 0) begin
        -- INSERT: Need to set the [Created] field
        --
        

        insert into [Employee] (
            [Code], 
            [Name],
            [Created], [Deleted]
            ) 
            output [inserted].[Id],[inserted].[Created],[inserted].[Deleted]  -- Need to OUTPUT this to return derived values to Entity Framework
        select [Code], 
            [Name],
            SYSUTCDATETIME(), [Deleted]
        from [inserted];

        

    end
return
end
```

## Calling Block:

@SpringBootApplication
public class GlMovementsApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

```
@Autowired
EmployeeService employeeService;

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setCode("bmw");
    emp.setName("bmw");

    Employee id = employeeService.saveEmployee(emp);

    System.out.println("id is: " +id.getId());
    System.out.println("code is: " +id.getCode());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GlMovementsApplication.class, args);

}
```

}

## Service Layer:

```
    @Service

public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao employeeDao;
    
    @Transactional()
    public Employee saveEmployee(Employee emp) {
        Employee object = null;
        try {
            object = employeeDao.save(emp);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Message: "+ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Cause: "+ex.getCause());
            System.out.println("stack trace: "+ex.getStackTrace());
        }
        return object;
    }
```

## DAO Layer:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeDao extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long>{
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add your `Employee` class?

Comment: And the definition of your trigger would be nice. Just take your time and take a look at the links I provided.

Comment: I don't think that Hibernate or Data JPA is able to handle the output. You should better have a look at jOOQ where such statements are not a problem https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual-single-page/#insert-returning

Comment: To figure out what's wrong, I would recommend capturing the SQL what is actually executed f. ex. using profiler, and also checking what happens if same SQL is executed with SSMS.

Comment: In its current state JPA will be seeing two rowcount alerts - one from the insert it sent, the other from the insert inside your trigger. You could try adding `set nocount on` to the beginning of your trigger, but I think JPA will still be confused by what it expects to be an INSERT statement actually returning a rowset.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks for the input. is there any other way to resolve this issue without altering trigger code. because we should not be allowed to change the database script. is it possible to resolve the issue using JPA alone?

Comment: You could try overriding CrudRepository.save() in your EmployeeDao class to get the behavior you want. I would not expect it to be trivial since your trigger is such an unusual implementation.